# How to copy empty directories with apache commons io?

Tags: java, io, directory, copy, apache-commons

I want to copy a directory tree with empty (but necessary!) directories with [apache commons io 2.1](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29). But it doesn't copy empty directories!

My code looks like this:

```
FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File(sourceDir), new File(targetDir));
```

Can I tell `FileUtils` to copy empty directories too? Or is it a bug in "commons io"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tested this myself using apache commons 2.1 (using the code line below) and for me it *does* copy empty directories too.

```
FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File("/home/aioobe/tmp/new_test"),
                        new File("/home/aioobe/tmp/new_test_2"));
```

with this structure

```
/home/aioobe/tmp/new_test
  hello.txt
  emptyDir/
```

Both `hello.txt` and `emptyDir` showed up in `new_test_2` as well.

Perhaps an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would be useful.

Comment: Me as well. Except I called it foobar.txt :-)

Comment: Thank you for verifying this! It was a bug in my maven-resources-plugin config (I've forgotten `<includeEmptyDirs>true</includeEmptyDirs>`).